# LFTP Connection Issue through SFTP & SSH Keys

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, lftp

I currently have Cygwin64 working on Windows with LFTP and LFTP OSX working fine when I have "Password Authorization yes" in sshd_config (Ubuntu Server 16.04). I can connect via SSH using my private keys just fine using PuTTY and terminal without any issue when I turn Password Authorization to no.

However, I cannot get LFTP to connect to my server when using key authorization only. "[Permission denied (publickey).]"

How do I get LFTP to access my private key when I have Password Authorization to no? I'd rather stick to key access exclusively.

I use LFTP due to its segmented downloading capabilities and really don't want to give it up.

Answer (score 2):

You can give ssh extra arguments using sftp:connect-program setting of lftp, like this:

```
set sftp:connect-program "ssh -ax -i key-file"
```

If ssh asks for the key pass phrase, then lftp gives it the password you used for login.